# Javascript - Load URL from input submit without "return: false;"

Tags: javascript

I have this form that executes blogSearch() on submit:

```
<form onsubmit="return blogSearch();">
  <input class="mb0" type="text" id="blogsearchinput" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function blogSearch() {
  var test = document.getElementById("blogsearchinput").value
  window.location.href = "../list.php";
  return false;
}
```

I want to run some more javascript in the function blogSearch() after the page loads, but obviously I can't do that after return false. The page will only load if I return false because I read that that will override the default input submit.

Is there are a way to load a URL from an input submit without needing return false? Or some way I can continue running a function after loading?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As soon as you load that new page the current page javascript is gone. Sounds like you want to use ajax and load content from list.php  into current page instead

Comment: I have a feeling that you are trying to use a wrong tool for the job. Please, give more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display search results on the same page using `window.location`, that
takes you to another page. In this case, you probably want to use a
[XHR request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to
get the data and then display it on the same page.

I've modified the HTML a little:

```
<form id="search-form">
  <label>Search blog: <input class="mb0" type="search" id="search-query"></label><input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<ul id="search-results"></ul>
```

Then in list.php you would do something like this:

```
<?php
// get the q parameter that we will be setting in our XHR request
$query = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '';

// I'm assuming you are returning a list of links, so I'm creating an
// array of associative arrays that contain url and link name info.
// In your actual application you would probably be pulling this data from a
// database instead, using the $query variable to filter the results that the DB
// returns. I would recommend using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection
// attacks. My PHP is really rusty right now so I'm not going to attempt to
// filter this array and just return the whole thing.
$results = array(
  array('name' => 'Foo', 'url' => '/foo'),
  array('name' => 'Bar', 'url' => '/bar'),
  array('name' => 'Baz', 'url' => '/baz'),
);

// encode our array as JSON so we can easily decode it in JavaScript
echo (json_encode($results));
?>
```

Then, here is the JS you would use to make the request and display the results.

```
// cache elements we will be using in variables
const searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");
const searchQuery = document.getElementById("search-query");
const searchResults = document.getElementById("search-results");

// this function will do the XHR request and display the results
function blogSearch(event) {

  // stops the default action, in this case submitting the form to the server
  event.preventDefault();

  // get the query and build a url to request
  let query = searchQuery.value;
  let url = `../list.php?q=${query}`;

  let displayError = () => {
    searchResults.innerHTML = '<li>There was an error retrieving your search results</li>';
  };

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.onload = () => {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // parse the JSON data that was returned
      let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

      // build up a list of li element containing links
      let html = ''
      data.forEach(item => {
        html += `<li><a href="${item.url}">${item.name}</a></li>`;
      });
      // display the search results in our unordered list
      searchResults.innerHTML = html;

    } else {
      displayError();
    }
  };

  request.onerror = () => {
    displayError();
  };

  request.send();
}

// attach the event to the search form
searchForm.addEventListener('submit', blogSearch, false);
```

A few notes on things I changed:

- Unless you are using XHTML, [you don't need to self-close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854998/778975) [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements).  (i.e. in my code I used `<input>` instead of `<input />`).
- I used a [label instead of a placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Labels_and_placeholders) because placeholders are meant for an example of valid input, not as a label. I also used [`type="search"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search) instead of `text` since this is meant to be a search box.
- I used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of an `onsubmit` to maintain [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
- I used [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions); all modern browsers support them (IE isn't modern).
- I used a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals); modern browsers support them (again IE is not modern).
- I used the modern `let` and `const` instead of `var` as any remotely modern browser supports them (even IE 11 supports them).

**Further reading**

- [`preventDefault` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- XHR code adapted from example at [YouMightNotNeedjQuery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)
- [Prepared statement with MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [SQL injection at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [SQL injection at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection)
- Obligatory [Bobby tables reference](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)
- [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/)